# Get all Posts If has same custom field values in Posts

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

Trying to get all the posts having the same zipcode as metavalue. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
<?php
                 $query = new WP_Query( array(
                         'post_type'=> array('service'),
                         'posts_per_page' => -1,
                         'meta_query' => array( array(
                              'key'=> 'zipcode',
                              'value'=> ','.$zip.',',
                              'compare'=> 'LIKE'
                             ) )
                         ));                 
?>      

    <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) :while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();  ?>
           <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php else: ?>
          No results found.
    <?php endif; ?>
```

zipcode are numbers for example `12345`. If posts have value `12345` in the custom field. then it should display all posts which have the `12345` value. The above code is working fine but displays only one post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will be the proper for the meta query.

```
  $query_args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'service',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query'  => array(
            array(
                'value'   => $zip,
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
                'key'     => 'zipcode',
            ),
        )
    );
   $query = new WP_Query($query_args);
   <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) :while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();  ?>
       <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
   <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
   <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
   <?php else: ?>
      No results found.
   <?php endif; ?>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This does the job for me:

```
$popularCourses = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        'post_type'         => 'courses', 
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'meta_key'          => 'course-is-promoted',
        'meta_value'        => 'Yes',
        'orderby'           => 'date',
        'order'             => 'DESC'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.

After watching this code i will suggest you just visit this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) for your better understanding.

(1)

```
    $args = array(
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'Your_key',//Enter your meta key here
           'value' => 'professionnel',//Enter you meta value
           'compare' => '=',//Comparison type (option filed) .
       )
   )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

(2)

```
$output_loop = get_posts( array(
    'meta_key'   => 'Your_key',//Meta key
    'meta_value' => 'Your_value',//Meta value
) );
```

Now just `print_r($output_loop)` for the better understanding.